# SAS : Data does not exist even tough they do

Tags: file-upload, import, sas

I am new in SAS environment. Maybe this is a stupid question but I cannot figure it out.

```
LIBNAME CODY '/folders/myfolders/Cody';

data In_Both
Missing_Name(drop = Name); 
merge purchase(in=In_Purch) 
inventory(in=In_Invent);
by Model;
if In_Purch and In_Invent then output In_Both; 
else if In_Invent and not In_Purch then output Missing_Name;
run;
```

This is the error I receive

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 72         
 73         LIBNAME CODY '/folders/myfolders/Cody';
 NOTE: Libref CODY was successfully assigned as follows: 
       Engine:        V9 
       Physical Name: /folders/myfolders/Cody
 74         
 75         data In_Both
 76         Missing_Name(drop = Name);
 77         merge purchase(in=In_Purch)
 78         inventory(in=In_Invent);
 ERROR: File WORK.PURCHASE.DATA does not exist.
 ERROR: File WORK.INVENTORY.DATA does not exist.
 79         by Model;
 80         if In_Purch and In_Invent then output In_Both;
 81         else if In_Invent and not In_Purch then output Missing_Name;
 82         run;
```

It seems that SAS cannot find the files even though they exists.
I'm using SAS university Edition.
The code should give me 2 datasets, one with the merged observation and another one with the unmerged observations.

Is there a specific way to load the datasets I need?
The two datasets are in format sas7bdat

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the merge statement in your code to

```
merge 
  CODY.purchase(in=In_Purch) 
  CODY.inventory(in=In_Invent)
;
```

The log is telling you the step is looking for tables in the `WORK` library, not `CODY`

Let's look at the original code.

```
data In_Both Missing_Name(drop = Name); 
  merge 
    purchase(in=In_Purch) 
    inventory(in=In_Invent)
  ;
  by Model;
  if In_Purch and In_Invent then output In_Both; 
  else 
  if In_Invent and not In_Purch then output Missing_Name;
run;
```

The data set names `purchase` and `inventory` in the `merge` do not include a `<libref>.`.  When a libref is not present, SAS will default to the `WORK` folder.

The error messages in the log clearly tells you the problem

```
ERROR: File WORK.PURCHASE.DATA does not exist.
ERROR: File WORK.INVENTORY.DATA does not exist.
```

You can see the step was looking for `WORK.PURCHASE` and `WORK.INVENTORY` and did not find them (because they are in the `CODY` library)

Change the data sets being merged to include the appropriate library, thus you want `CODY.purchase` and `CODY.inventory`

Comment: How do I tell SAS to look in Cody folder instead of Work? Sorry I did not get fully your answer

Comment: Change the data set name from just `PURCHASE` (which implies`WORK.PURCHASE`) to `CODY.PURCHASE`

Comment: Thanks now I got it!